# RNN with LSTM for demand forecasting

Tags: time-series

How should one prepare the input to RNN LSTM network with datetime as index and one categorical value for demand forecast?
i have 800 datapoints and my data is is in the form:

```
Date          Demand  Holiday
1/2/2015    203  0
1/5/2015    370  0
1/6/2015    8    1
1/7/2015    388  0
1/8/2015    19   1
1/9/2015    376  0
1/12/2015   343  0
1/13/2015   430  1
```

kindly suggest..

```
Date       Demand  Holiday

1/2/2015    203     0
1/5/2015    370     0
1/6/2015    8       1
1/7/2015    388     0
1/8/2015    19      1
1/9/2015    376     0
1/12/2015   343     0
1/13/2015   430     1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should decompose the Date column (example: day of week, week of year, year). Then, as a best practice you should think about encoding cyclic features using a polar representation (cos, sin) or simply by using a dummy representation (one-hot encoding).
Finally, you have only to build your LSTM model (may be sequential) and give a lot of attention to how you define your model's input/output shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample you published, your data is missing some dates. normally I would suggest some form of smoothing or interpolation, but your data is very weird and lumpy (370, then 8, then  388), so smoothing or interpolation won't work. Nor does it seem to correlate with the holiday in any meaningful way. So before thinking about an LSTM or an RNN, I would look at cleaning up or improving your data.